# How to track user's action on another site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, setcookie

I am doing coupon gifting platform.I am working on rails platform.

My problem is I want to track whether user performed checkout using the coupon given by my site or not.

Means suppose I am running xyz.com to provide gift coupons of abc.com. Then if any user  checkouts using the coupon code from my site how I will come to know about that?

Comment: do you have access to abc.com

Comment: amm abc.com is the eCommerce site which provides coupons so it can be e.g. snapdeal or flipkart

Comment: means I want to know, if I am sending 500 users to abc.com then how many of them actually used the coupon & bought something.Can I know that?

Comment: I still dont understand your question. Is it that your abc.com and you give away coupons to be used on flipcart or snapdeal. Now you want to know how many of the people used your coupoun on flipcart or snapdeal ?

Comment: ok listen suppose I am like coupondunia.in i.e I am publisher, showing coupons of jabong.com on my site ok. Now when suppose user sees coupon from my site & then checkouts on jabong using that code. Then is there any way so that I can come to know that the checkout was performed through the coupon code from my site? Means actual acquisition happened on jabong using the code displayed on my site?

Comment: This is not possible until the jabong.com give you some sort of access to his purchases using coupons data. This is a basic thing dude you should have googled it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible until the other site give you some sort of access to his purchases using coupons data.

Comment: ok then I have a another question.There is site paisalive.com which shows you ads from different brands and once you sign up/register to that websites by clicking on the ads shown by them they pay you certain amount. Now how paisalive actually validates or find out I have registered to the site or not? Means if I do not register to the advertisers site it doesn't pay me and vice versa so I want to do kind of similar thing.. How to do that?

Comment: This works in a similar way how you refer a friend to a site and they pay you for each friend of your signed on the site through you. There are basically two ways either have a special link like /register/yourname and if some one uses this you get bonus or else they would have some referee number that they use while registering. In your case the first thing is used

Comment: pasialive.com will not validate that I have registered through it. The site will tell pasialive.com that we have so many people through you.